# How to avoid call of constructor?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am creating project using REST API with ASP.NET and AngularJS.

My repository:

```
Class MyRepository {
    private int myVariable;
    public MyRepository() {
        myVariable = 100;
    }

    public int getMyVariable() {
        return myVariable;
    }

    public int Update(int data) {
        myVariable = data;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public Class MyController : ApiController {
    private MyRepository repository = new MyRepository();

    [Route("myRoute")]
    public int getVariable() {
         return getMyVariable();
    }

    [Route("myRoute")]
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult Update(int data)
    {
        data = repository.Update(data);
        return Ok(data);
    }
}
```

Methods in JS service:

```
getMyNumber = function () {
    return $http.get("/myRoute");
};

updateMyNumber = function (number) {
    return $http.put("/myRoute", number);
}
```

Firstly I call function `getMyNumber`. The result is 100 (ok). Then I update it to 50. Having a breakpoint I can see that it is really 50 in repository. When I call `getMyNumber` function again, the result is 100.

Looks like constructor of `MyController` is called with my each request. If so, what is the way to update data and work with updated data?

Comment: Consider adding a constructor to your ApiController and inject an instance of your repository via dependency injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the controller is scoped to each request so you are newing it up, along with your repository object, every time there is a request.  It sounds like you are avoiding the need for a db and don't need any persistence beyond the lifetime of the application.  So in that case, what you is to store a value with application lifetime scope which means dealing with concurrency.  Perhaps what you need is one of the solutions described here: http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2010/12/container-based-pseudosingletons-in.html